# Spanish letters on German keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am using a German keyboard layout and I would like to add the Spanish letters to the keys.
Is there a way to add the Spanish letter ñ to the keybind: "Alt-Gr n" and the letter Ñ to the keybind "Alt-Gr+Shift N"?
I would like to do it with "regedit" but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can do this, using the following script:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

<^>!n::Send ñ
<^>!+n::Send Ñ
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called Ac'tivAid which can do these kinds of so called HotStrings. I personally use it for frensh letter ç and Ç with the combination of cc# and CC# respecitvely to type it. It can be found on [Heise](https://www.heise.de/download/product/activaid-24593) so you know it is a secure download. It is programmed in AutoHotKey, but that comes with the installer.

In addition to being able to write foreign language letters, I use it e.g. to autotype my mail and so on. There are multiple tools you can install from within the menu, most of them are not really necessary, but some are really useful. The one you are looking for is "HotStrings" as I mentioned earlier.